# Which was the first science fiction story to feature a railgun?

Tags: history-of

In *The Expanse* (2015) one of the secondary characters' head is chopped off clean by another spaceship's railgun.

In *Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen (2009)*, a destroyer(?) fires a railgun to take out Devastator.

In *Toaru Kagaku no Railgun (A Certain Scientific Railgun)* (2007) The main character Mikasa is an esper capable of firing a railgun with her hands.

But what was the first story to show one?
Which was the first science fiction story to feature a railgun?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagneticWeapons

Comment: I do know the Justice League Animated Series from early 2000s featured some kind of satellite asteroid magnetic launcher as a weapon, but I doubt it's the earliest work listed on TvTropes.

Comment: Many of the earliest works seem to be listed early 2000s or late 90s. There's Warhammer 40.000 which was created in 1987, although I don't know when exactly the first work featuring a railgun was released.

Comment: @Clockwork well, you could post it as answer and put the link as a reference, the fact that there are works listed in TVTropes doesnt necessarily mean they have the first one, so may be another user finds another later

Comment: [Raiguns (and Gauss guns) are actual things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun).